# Reason for optimum number of threads

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I would like to know if I've written this correctly, and get any further details or illuminations (in particular, the description of context switching):

> On *my* machine (using an Intel Core i7), I have four cores, each presenting two
>   hardware threads (e.g. processors, using the hardware trick called
>   *hyperthreading*). Although this is a common configuration on "recent" machines
>   (at the time of this writing), you might see a different result---along with an
>   equivalent number of default threads in parallel `Stream` programs.
>
> It turns out that the "generic" optimal number of threads is the number of
>   processors available (this might not be true for specific problems). This comes
>   from the cost of *context switching* between threads: storing the current state
>   of the thread being suspended and retrieving the other thread's current state to
>   start execution from where it entered suspension. If you have eight processors
>   and eight threads, the JVM never has to switch contexts when running eight
>   tasks. If you have fewer tasks than the number of processors then it doesn't
>   help to allocate more threads.

**Note:** I'm relating this to the reason that both parallel streams and `Executors.newWorkStealingPool()` produce (on my machine) 8 threads.

**Note2:** When you call `Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()`, it returns 8 on my machine. So I'm describing "what Java considers a processor."

Comment: This is not correct, in general.  In particular, if some of those threads are doing nothing at any given time, it's advantageous to have more threads to use that spare time.

Comment: If you're going to say "optimum number of threads", then you probably ought to say _for what_.    What you describe might be the optimum number of threads for a CPU bound computation with unlimited opportunities for parallism, running as the only process on a machine, but that does not mean it's the optimum number of threads for some other application.

Comment: A "hardware thread" is not a "processor".  A "core" is a "processor."  A hyperthreaded core creates the illusion of two _virtual_ processors because it has two complete sets of context registers, and it can switch back and forth between the two contexts in essentially zero time.  Depending on the level of sophistication, it may have _limited_ ability to work on both at the same time (most often, by performing arithmetic operations on behalf of one thread while the other thread is waiting to fetch something from memory.)

Comment: I rewrote the two paragraphs in question.

Comment: I think that you should have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl%27s_law
It's a kind of theorisation of your problem. 
Just, when it's said in the article, please read it as "number of parallel computing units", such as logical cores. 

In fact you can always just have a upper bound of the speedup as the architecture of modern CPUs are very complicated. For instance, some instructions can be done in parallel while other not. 

Anyway, Amdahl's law can be a good rule of thumb :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not quite as simple as that; a lot depends on what the threads are doing.  If your threads are all very compute intensive, the optimal number of threads may be the same as the number of processor cores to avoid the overhead of context switches.  However, if your threads perform I/O, or otherwise are occasionally blocked on resources, then it can be advantageous to have more threads than cores so as to avoid wasting cores when threads are blocked.

In addition, Intel hyperthreading does not generally increase compute capability; the feature maintains extra thread contexts at a hardware level but does not increase the computational capacity.  Thus, for compute intensive threads, it may be better to match the number of threads to the number of physical cores, and ignore hyperthreading.  Hyperthreading is primarily useful when the threads do get blocked occasionally, as most of the cost of context switching to the other hyperthread on the processor can be avoided when one thread gets blocked.

Note:  with respect to the additional notes added to the question, the fact that Java "sees" each hyperthread as a processor is basically a bug introduced by Intel's excessive hype of hyperthreads; computational throughput is maximized when the number of active threads is the number of physical processors, not the number of hyperthreads, and thus a work stealing pool with the machine to itself works best with a target number of threads equal to the number of physical processors.  Java's default works well on most processors, but isn't quite optimal on Intel processors with hyperthreading.  If you're interested in additional details, I'd suggest looking at my answer to another question, which describes tests that I performed regarding the optimal number of computational threads on an Intel processor:

[Multithreading - are the multi-core processors really doing parallel processing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24025123/multithreading-are-the-multi-core-processors-really-doing-parallel-processing/24026825#24026825)

Comment: Our comments happened at the same time; see the first note above. I am attempting to describe why streams and workStealingPools (and probably some other things I haven't discovered) choose the number of processors as the optimal number of threads. The number seems well accepted, but I'm trying to be clear on the "why" -- which I think is the cost of context switching, based on what I've read, but it could be something else.

Comment: Added a paragraph responding to your notes.  My basic answer remains the same, though.

Comment: I think it's worth repeating Ollie Jones' comment here: "The "hyperthreads" are hardware support for efficient context-switching, and are most beneficial for workloads where high-priority non computationally intensive threads need to interrupt lower priority ones. This makes graphic user interfaces more responsive."

Comment: Also, egads. Is there no concurrency question for which there is a simple answer? "Leaky Abstraction," indeed. I think I will need to include some heavy footnoting with these details.

Comment: Still, though. The computer is actually running a lot more than 4 or 8 threads---it's not just running your Java app, but also doing everything else on your computer. Many OS threads. So it seems like the faster context switching afforded by hyperthreading would ultimately be useful.

Comment: I agree that perhaps the hyperthreads may be useful to reduce context switching for OS threads that run briefly.  However, we don't need to dedicate threads in our application for that purpose, since as you note, the OS already has its own threads for that.

Comment: With respect to simple answers, I think the problem is that concurrency is inherently complicated, or at least difficult for humans to work with.  I will note that Java attempted early on to make threading repeatable with software based "green threads", but those proved problematic when trying to take advantage of multiple core machines on hardware threads.  Possibly if Sun had ever implemented the JVM in hardware, that could have been taken care of, but then again, it's possible that repeatability would inherently cause loss of threading efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

*Warren Dew*'s answer does not apply to some multi-processor machines, and I'm not confident that it is correct for Intel processors. Hyper-threading on some machines **does** increase throughput even in the complete absence of blocking or I/O or graphics! In particular, on a machine with 32 SPARC cores each supporting up to 8 logical processors (via hyper-threading), the peak throughput for a work-stealing scheduler was somewhere between 64 and 128 worker threads. There was significant difference in speedup when going from 32 to 64 worker threads; the speedup jumped from ×20 to ×29.

Note that each of the worker threads were started only once and there were no other threads. Also, this work-stealing scheduler has essentially no blocking, since each deque access has O(1) expected contention. Moreover, the test computation run using this scheduler was purely computational, with only manipulation of pointer data structures. Thus the above results can only be explained if hyper-threading on SPARC cores truly yields a higher throughput than having just one thread per core.

Of course, the optimal number of threads always depends on what exactly you want to compute and what machine you want to use. But Java's choice of using the number of processors instead of the number of logical cores is an entirely reasonable one. If you do experiments and find another choice better, obviously use your own discretion. But in the absence of empirical data, you should probably not dismiss Java's default.

By the way, I was using my own work-stealing scheduler, which was about 5 times more efficient than Java's but only supports purely computational tasks. So I cannot assert anything for Java's ForkJoinPool with work-stealing.